# Prepopulate Exposed Group Filter with relevant values

Tags: views

I have a view which displays the venues (including city), dates and times shows are being performed at. Once a date passes the listing disappears.

There are more shows in the database than are being performed at any one time and new shows are added occasionally.

Using an exposed filter (grouped) I want a user to be able to select from a list of shows that is scheduled to perform or from a list of cities we are touring to.

As the lists of cities and shows changes on a weekly, sometimes daily, basis I don't want people to have to go in and edit the view to add or remove shows or cities from the  redefined lists and to do it programatically instead.

I have a table (node-type) for shows, another for venues, and a third for performances which uses node-reference to to state X-show at Y-venue and then adds performance details.

My view pulls from the performance type where the performance is greater than or equal to now (only showing future performances), with relationships to the Shows type to get the name of the show and another relationship to get the name/boxoffice/location/etc of the venue.

My view works fine with manually entered values into the 'configure filter criteron' - but this needs to be updated dynamically.

Can anyone suggest anything to make it work, or another approach to the problem which may be more apt?

Thank you.

System: Drupal 7, Views 7.x-3